# How do I make express-handlebars be rendered on apache server?

Tags: node.js, apache2, express-handlebars, hbs

To learn how to use handlebars with Express, I followed this tutorial and it worked perfectly:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handlebars-templating-in-expressjs/

Now, I'm trying to make it work for production. So, instead of rendering the page as it was supposed to, it shows {{demo.name}}, not the name I have for "demo".

I haven't found anything related to Apache server and handlebars.
Here's my virtual host configuration:

- VirtualHost
  /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.com.br.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *80>
   ServerName mydomain.com.br
   ServerAlias www.mydomain.com.br
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   DocumentRoot /var/www/teste_hbs/views
</VirtualHost>
```

- app.js
  /var/www/teste_hbs/app.js

```
import express from 'express';
import hbs from 'hbs';

const app=express();

app.set("view engine", "hbs"); 
app.set('views', './views' )

let demo = {
    name: 'Rohan',
    age: 26
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('dynamic', { demo: demo })
})
app.listen(5000);
```

- dynamic.hbs:
  /var/www/teste_hbs/views/dynamic.hbs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
       <p>{{demo.name}} is {{demo.age}} years old.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

The result I'm having for mydomain.com.br/dynamic.hbs:

`{{demo.name}} is {{demo.age}} years old.`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are just serving your handlebars template with Apache. In order to have the Express app work, you would need a Node.js server running the Express app.